# Prove that $(p\oplus q)\oplus r$ is logically equivalent to $p\oplus (q \oplus r)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am reviewing for my upcoming Discrete Mathematics class and I'm clueless on the aforementioned question. I've tried expounding the XOR operator in hopes of transforming the problem but still I cannot find the solution to the problem.

The title is pretty self-explanatory, how do I prove their logical equivalence without using a truth table?

The truth table of the problem looks like this:

Problem truth table

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a truth table?

Comment: I guess I want to have a comprehensive understanding of the topic.

Answer (score 1):

XOR evaluates to `true` when there are "odd" number of `true` inputs. So the order and association don't matter. You may think of XOR as$\mod 2$ operator. As an example,
$$odd + even +even =  odd $$ 
It doesn't matter how you order or associate the inputs.